# Why "lcd_puts" doesn't display the value of a variable at LCD 16*2?

Tags: c, embedded, printf, microcontroller, avr

I tried to display a value at a LCD in proteus simulator by the following code which is written in Codevision:

```
sprintf(buffer,"Temp=%f\xdfC\n",temp);
lcd_puts(buffer);
```

but the value of temp doesn't appear in front of "temp=" at LCD!

[image]

the whole code is:

```
 #include <mega16.h>
 #include <delay.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <alcd.h> 

 char buffer[32];
 float temp=26.3457;  


void main(void){    
    lcd_init(16);

    while(1){

      lcd_clear();
      sprintf(buffer,"Temp=%f\xdfC\n",temp);
      lcd_puts(buffer);
      delay_ms(1500);
    }
}
```

Comment: I only guess. Your sprintf doesn't support `%f` or it's disabled, you can test first with `%d` and look at the compiler/linker settings

Comment: Like Jeb says. Small embedded systems seldom support full floating point, you need to check with your compiler and platform documentation first. Also, are you sure the display driver support non-ASCII characters? And if it does, are you sure about the character set contains the character you think it does with value `0xdf`?

Comment: IIRC you need a compiler flag to enable float in printf on the mega16.

Comment: @Jasen could you please tll me how I can do it?

Comment: might be you need `-lprintf_flt` on the gcc command-line

Comment: As the op mentioned he's using the CodeVision toolchain, but at this point it should be said that you should think about changing your toolchain to gcc (this is only my personal opinion about codevision vs gcc)

Comment: Simple answer: do not use floating point on AVR and other small devices. For temperature you do not even need it, but integer emulating fixed-point (decimal or binary) is the way to go.

Comment: @mehdiamirsardari,  sorry, can't.  when all else fails RTFM

Comment: @Olaf is right; in this case there is no need for floating point.  First it is unlikely that you can actually accurately measure temperature to 6 significant figures or that it will be that stable that such a display is meaningful.  Display to a 10th of a degree is probably adequate for all but the most carefully controlled (and small and well insulated) environments.  In that case simply store or calculate temperature as an integer in tenths of a degree and display thus `"Temp=%d.%d\xdfC\n", temp \ 10, temp % 10`.

Answer (score 2):

need add this argument to compiler:

```
-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm
```

without this will be `%f` ignored

more info is in [avr-libc documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, as this would work for the gcc toolchain, but the OP mentioned that CodeVision is used

Comment: I appreciate if you tell me how and where I can add this code?please tell me step by step.thank you.now I opend stdio.lib but where can I add it?

Comment: Yes it is for GCC and in CodeVision is maybe another kind of compiler, so in this case is better solution from jeb.

Answer (score 2):

For CodeVision you need to change the `(s)printf Features` settings in the `Configure Project` dialog to `float, width, precision`.

Comment: What do you got now with the changed settings?

Comment: the settings were exactly like you said,it's set on **float, width, precision**

Comment: The question was: What do you see on your display now?

Comment: I see the sent picture in my question block

Answer (score 1):

The `\x` escape sequence is problematic, because it keeps reading the string for as long as there are valid digits. In your case you told it to print the symbol table character equivalent to hex number `0xdfc` which is not the intention. If you are unlucky, this will corrupt the buffer somehow, which would lead to some random output.

Fix the code by ending the literal and start a new one just after it:

```
sprintf(buffer, "Temp=%f\xdf" "C\n", temp);
```

A decent compiler would warn you against accessing the symbol table out-of-bounds.

Comment: Since the display shows the degree symbol and the C, it seems that this is not the case in this instance at least.  `\xdf` is a character escape sequence and in this case presumably reads the number of digits corresponding to the character set of the execution environment.